# Glide v4 Configuration doesn't load

Tags: android, android-glide

I have implemented Glide Module it seems it does not loaded at all

This is my Dependencies

```
dependencies
{
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

GlideHandler.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class GlideHandler extends AppGlideModule
{
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry)
    {
        Log.d("registerComponents Called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled()
    {
        Log.d("isManifestParsingEnabled Called");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Proguard:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.AppGlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.HardwareConfigState
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever
```

Did I forgot something? Those method doesn't call

Comment: looks fine to me. What error you getting ? How are you making a call to load url /image ?